# Se puede eliminar una opcion de un select creado dinamicamente con mareial-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui, dropdown

soy muy nuevo en react y material-IU. Esta es la estructura que se le pasa a cada selector para configurarlo y que muestra las tres opciones por defecto

```
export const questionOptions = {
  defaultValue: undefined,
  control: {
    type: "select",
    options: {      
      Accept: true,
      Decline: false,
      Unknown: undefined,
    },
  },
};
```

Y así es como cada componente está configurado para el título y sus opciones

```
export const types = {
  startAdornment: {
  title: "First Text",
  ...questionOptions,
  },
  startAdornment: {
  title: "Second Text",
  ...questionOptions,
  },
}
```

Tengo que crear un tercer select y quiero mostrar sólo las dos primeras opciones pero no sé cómo hacer para que no se muestre la tercera dentro del propio componente.

```
startAdornment: {
  title: "Third Text",
  // just the first two options,
  },
```

Alguien que me dé una idea de cómo conseguir esto... ¿Habría una manera de eliminar una opción en el spread operator?

Gracias a todos por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facil clonas el objeto y manipulas el objeto exitos.